# Create instances of a variable in Javascript and access variable within an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var objSample = {
   variable: 10,
   func1 : function(){
       someJQueryPlugin(1, function(){
             this.variable; // this doesn't work, don't have access
       });
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1) How can I create an instance of the variable so I can have two stand alone objects, each one with its own unique variable values?

Example:

```
var obj1 = new objSample();
obj1.variable = 1;

var obj2 = new objSample();
obj2.variable = 2;
```

2) How can I have access to the variable inside an anonymous function from a jQuery plugin inside a function in the object. passing `this` didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var objSample = function(){
  this.variable = 10
   this.func1 = function(){
       someJQueryPlugin(1, function(){
             this.variable; <-- this doesn't work, don't have access
       });
    }
}
```

also you can extend constructor with params

```
 var objSample = function(options){
  this.variable = options.val
   this.func1 = function(){
       someJQueryPlugin(1, function(){
             this.variable; <-- this doesn't work, don't have access
       });
    }
}
var obj1  = new objSample ({val:1})
var obj2  = new objSample ({val:2})
```

and to access `this`  from callbacks in different context, enclose this to some variable.
So final code looks like:

```
 var objSample = function(options){
      var self = this;
      self.variable = options.val
       self.func1 = function(){
           someJQueryPlugin(1, function(){
                 self.variable;
           });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot for the quick response Gena.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the code from an object literal to a constructor function and ensure that you reference the right `this` in the `func1` function.

```
function ObjSample() {
  this.variable = 10;
  this.func1 = function () {
    var _this = this;
    someJQueryPlugin(1, function () {
      _this.variable;
    });
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AJ5pW/1/)